# Android: How to make function wait for another?

Tags: android, function, wait

I want to send an sms message containing current location of user. How do I make the sending function wait till the location is calculated?

Comment: can it be done this way, calculate location first and then send message......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private class DeafLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    private final String provider;

    public DeafLocationListener(String provider) { this.provider = provider; }

    @Override public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("onLocationChanged triggered (%s)", provider));
        // SEND SMS HERE
    }
    @Override public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { /*nop*/ }
    @Override public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { /*nop*/ }
    @Override public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { /*nop*/ }

}

LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTimeGPS, minDistanceGPS, new DeafLocationListener("GPS"););
```

Comment: Wont this send the sms whenever the location is changed?

Comment: Remove the listener when your sms is sent? This is pure application logic.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and you will find out. The trick is you issue an intent when you get the location.

Comment: can you please provide me some code or link to an example? I am new to android. I cant seem to understand how to get it done.